# socket.io - How to display data from server.js in an HTML page?

Tags: html, node.js, websocket, socket.io

How can i display data ( the number of the connected users from socket.client.conn.server.clientsCount) from server.js  in html page?

eg: from server.js to chat.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could send it via the socket from the backend and then process it in frontend:

**Backend:**

```
socket.emit('count', socket.client.conn.server.clientsCount);
```

**Frontend:**

```
socket.on('count', c => { document.querySelector('#count').textContent = c });
```

Comment: i did very similar thing in the frontend but messed up the backend , Thank you this solved my problem

Comment: [https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/](https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/)